# Mongoose and Query Injection when using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, code-injection

[How does MongoDB address SQL or Query injection?](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#how-does-mongodb-address-sql-or-query-injection) explains how to handle query injection with BSON when using javascript on the server. I haven't been able to track down how/whether [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) handles query injection though.

At this point I have two questions:

1. Does Mongoose protect against query injection (using BSON or some other method)
2. If it does,  are there any quirks with it's implementation that a developer need to be aware of?

Answer (score 3):

Mongoose does not protect against query injection so unfortunately you will need to perform your own injection detection following the guidelines from the link above.

Comment: mongoose does caste properties according to the schema, though. Can you explain why that is not enough?

Comment: That link refers to two types of injection: query injection (which drivers should take care of, if they construct queries as BSON) and JavaScript injection (which can be avoided with careful/sparing use of $where, db.eval, mapReduce, and group). Can you speak in more detail about how Mongoose (or the underlying mongodb-native driver) address these two types of injection?